# Node JS and Firebase Unable to Search Using equal.To()

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I've started reading into creating Google Actions using Node.JS/Dialogflow/Firebase.

I have reached a big stumbling block, in trying to get a simple code running that would search a Firebase database for a certain value and then report back. For example from the JSON output, I would like to search for the applicationID and have the age passed back as the output.

I would be extremely grateful if someone can review my code and direct me in the right direction.

**Table Structure**

```
{
  "groupA" : {
    "applications" : {
      "100" : {
        "age" : 20,
        "result" : "pass"
      },
      "200" : {
        "age" : 25,
        " result " : "pass"
      },
      "500" : {
        "age" : 20,
        " result " : "fail"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Node JS**

```
    return admin.database().ref('groupA').child('applications').orderByChild('applications').equalTo(500)
                  .once('value')
                  .then(acceptedApplicationsSnapshot => {
       var id = acceptedApplicationsSnapshot.val().age;
      var data = acceptedApplicationsSnapshot.val();
   var theAge = acceptedApplicationsSnapshot.child("age").val();
      agent.add('some random text' + theAge);
    });
```

Within this example the value 500 should be searched with the age then given as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ordering/filtering on property `applications`, but the value you're passing in is a **key**. So you'll want to use `orderByKey` instead of `orderByChild`:

```
return admin.database().ref('groupA').child('applications').orderByKey().equalTo(500)
```

A query may match multiple child nodes, so the above returns a snapshot with a list of results. Even when there's only one result, the query will return a list of one result:

```
{
  "500": {
    "age" : 20,
    " result " : "fail"
 }
}
```

This means that you'll need to loop over the results in your callback:

```
acceptedApplicationsSnapshot.forEach(appSnapshot => {
  var theAge = appSnapshot.child("age").val();
  agent.add('some random text' + theAge)
})
```

---

Since you know the exact key of the child node you want, you can also simply keep using `child()` to access the specific node:

```
return admin.database().ref('groupA').child('applications').child('500')
```

This will result in a snapshot of that specific node being returned, instead of the list-with-a-single-child-node of the previous snippet.

```
{
    "age" : 20,
    " result " : "fail"
}
```

And then you can use your existing code to retrieve the `age` from the snapshot.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great - thanks once again, your help has been greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To search for the **applicationsID=500** and have the **age** passed back as the output, you can try this.

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("groupA").child("applications/500").once('value')
     .then(function(dataSnapshot){
          console.log(dataSnapshot.val().age);
});
```

More info **[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).**

**Edited:** This should give you the age, in this case equals 20, for the parameter you pass in **applications/500** in the code above.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your help - it is greatly appreciated. Unfortnately, it produces the following error: 'ReferenceError: child is not defined' in the console log